# Apple ARKit inaccurate on iPhone x

Tags: arkit, iphone-x

I work for Stanley Black&Decker, doing high accuracy measuring with ARKit.  I have been testing with an iPhone7+ and iPad Pro (extensively since July), and accuracy between AR and real world is pretty good (within a few inches over 40' for example).  However, with iPhone X, the accuracy is off - by a foot or more over 40'.   In fact the iPhone X seems to incorrectly scale everything by maybe 3% to 8% too small (for example 45' reality shows as 42' 2" AR).   Has anyone else seen differences between models?

UPDATE: Excellent.  There are (as you mentioned) several layers of abstraction.  At the base is Visual Inertial Odometry - that uses (random) feature point "cloud", gyro, accelerometer to establish a world origin.   The next layer is hz plane detection (plane anchors).  It appears that every frame (60fps) ARKit re-calculates (re-Estimates) world origin based on VIO.   This induces a background jitter (usually +- 1mm/axis).  If Feature point cloud gets too small, or changes too fast, world origin detection becomes hard to estimate, or is inconclusive, loss of origin continuity.

But there is another condition where origin and plane anchors have NOT changed, but the POV instantaneously (in 16ms) jumps by .5 to 2.5m meters. So ARKit incorrectly thinks POV has moved - aka iPhone physically jumped.  Somewhat opposite of elevator where iPhone DID move, but feature point cloud did not.

An unknown is if plane anchors "feed back" into world origin (or POV) estimation.  I do not think so.  If one or more planes are in view (fustrum) then there should not be a slippage - but there is.  So it appears world origin is only determined by VIO and feature point cloud, hence, plane anchors can move relative to origin, and jitter, and they do.

On the original question, I use iPhone7 and iPhoneX side by side, both detect the same (single) plane (on the floor).  But as I slowly move from starting point, iPhone7 position (either by scnHit or Pov) is pretty accurate (4m is 4m).  While the iPhoneX seems to underestimate the position (4m shows as 3.5m)

Answer (score 1):

Yes model shifts for longer distance in ARKit.

ARKit works by mapping environment and placing virtual coordinates on top. So when you start ARKit app first it searches for and creates anchor for the real world where it can find enough feature points. As we move around these anchors are added for different real world objects or places. And it tries to match already found places with created anchors and position virtual world (3D coordinates) accordingly.

You know if enough feature point is not found model shifts from its place because it gets confused between real and virtual positioning. And when anchor is added in these case we will have origin of virtual world shifted for this anchor.

Say when AR session started the origin was in one corner of a table and you have model placed in center of table. Now when you moved to next end of table and the model shifts to edge of the table because it did not find enough feature point. And suddenly it found new anchor when model is on the edge. Now what happens is it have two anchors for two ends of table. If you move your camera to first end of table it matches with first anchor and model is placed on center of table. And if you move your camera to next end, it matches with second anchor and shifts the model to edge of the table.

And this chance increases with increase in distance.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to overcome this?

Comment: No, I think we can only wait till they come up with better algorithm or upgrade the hardware. It is beyond my knowledge at least

Comment: Hi, I'm making app for room measurement. When measuring small objects like screen keyboards, the mapped object in view are little irregular shape. But while measuring room the mapped shapes are very irregular.  Can you suggest me any approach?